# jre not installed on firefox when using Citrix Access Gateway

Tags: networking, firefox, java, jre, citrix

I'm trying to get to my vpn / citrix access gateway using Firefox 38.0 for Ubuntu Canonical 1.0 Ubuntu 14.04 and when I try to log in I get this error: JRE is not installed on your machine. Install JRE and retry. I've already installed a jre using `sudo apt-get install default-jre`. I also have java installed at `/opt/java/jre1.8.0_45` and I can run java from my command prompt some its certainly on my class path.

```
$java -version
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)`
```

my bashrc file has:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_05
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH`
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Which JRE? OpenJRE or Oracle? [Edit] your question and add the output of `java -version`

Comment: Test your Java version in firefox: https://www.java.com/de/download/installed.jsp?detect=jre

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to allow Java applets in your browser.

1. Install the Java Plugin

   `sudo apt-get install icedtea-plugin`
2. Click the menu button, choose Add-ons.
3. In the Add-ons Manager tab, select the Plugins panel.
4. Activate, if necessary, the Java Plugin
5. Start a [test](https://www.java.com/de/download/installed.jsp?detect=jre)

   *If the plugin doesn't work correctly, than follow the next steps.*
6. Install the Oracle Java (with the Java Plugin) with a PPA

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
   ```
7. ***After that*** set Oracle Java 8 as default

   ```
    sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
   ```

Comment: java plugin is not in my Plugins list. Is there an easy way to get it installed?

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: I have the plugin installed but now when I go to the main page I just get a blank screen. usually on the main page is where you enter my credentials and upon opening submit is when the popup appears and i get the no JRE installed message. The JRE perhaps is now installed since the behavior is different but i don't seem to be getting as far. Perhaps where is a way to do this with Chrome or someway to troubleshoot? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @simgineer I have updated my answer.

Comment: I think its working but I'll verify later. DNS does not seem to be very friendly right now.

Comment: And, works it now?

Comment: I didn't get to test it this weekend. Will try to do this tonight. I'm going to mark this as the answer since it so clearly helps to get java working in my version of Firefox. I'll see to allocating the bonus on actually getting on the network remotely. Again thank you. :)

Comment: Well I can surf to websites on the internal network but am not able to ssh, us hg (mercurial) or ping internal sites like in can when I tunnel in on my win7 system. I need to be able to use mercurial at the very least.

Comment: Any error messages? What is you `ssh` and/or your `hg` command

Comment: `ssh: connect to host 128.1.1.176 port 22: Connection timed out`  when i pull I get `remote:ssh: connect to host 128.1.1.176 port 22: Connection timed out` <new line> `abort: no suitable response from remote hg!`

Comment: Looks like there is a local proxy that is setup using my remote access server java client on 3128. And this is taking care of my websites. If I can get something similar for my ssh traffic i'll be in good shape. :)